# How can I make Private Messages in Drupal 7 with user user pictures like in Facebook?

Tags: theming, users, privatemsg

There are many people who want to see their Private Message module in Drupal to look like Facebook - i.e. with user pictures.  Pictures make messages more "personal" and "closer" than e-mails.
I made it work in D5 and D6 by putting functions into template.php, but for D7 I can't find any such snippet that would work for D7.

I've written more about this here http://drupal.org/node/1549540  There's already much of the snippet there, but the DB query returns an error.

Can someone please help write a lasting solution for drupal user in D7?

Answer (score 3):

that's a great idea, I would love to see that too. Wouldn't it be easier replacing the default page with a view? Then you can style it any way you want. The "checkboxes" and actions could be done with VBO.

Comment: Your right, altering the form and overriding stuff could be hefty. although I wish I could see how a sub-module would integrate.